# How can I bring back the title bar in Nautilus and Document viewer?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, titlebar

I've noticed that the classical title bars are missing from Nautilus and Document Viewer. It has been going for a sleeker hidden title bar. However, I prefer the older version. Is there anyway to bring back normal title bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your classical title bar back by installing `gtk3-nocsd` using Synaptic package manager or the command line:

```
sudo apt install gtk3-nocsd
```

While this will perfectly answers your question as you asked it, note that this will not bring back a classical menu bar. This package merely returns control of the windows decorations (titlebar, window control buttons) to your window manager.

More information on how to configure the tool can be found on the projects [Github page](https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd).

Comment: [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html) might help

Comment: Thank you. To remain "neutral", I linked to the documentation on the Github page. Actually, that option is already provided in the post linked as a duplicate, in the solution of Guss, so indeed this post is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like for Ubuntu 18.04 after installing gtk3-nocsd I have to use it to open the application i.e, "gtk3-nocsd evince" or "gtk3-nocsd nautilus". Unfortunately, it looks terrible with this enabled. If viewing a pdf it will have the title in the client side style menu bar and the system style title bar added above that. No way to completely remove the csd title bar, unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed, the header of the CSD apps stays the same. nocsd merely adds the window decorations of your WM, as I indicated in my answer. The Hithub page or the page linked by Vijay in the comments indicate how to set system variable such that nocsd is automatically applied, without having to change the command line.

Comment: If using Mint XFCE, go to Settings and choose Preferred Applications. Click the Utilities tab then under File Manager choose Other. Type `gtk3-nocsd nautilus "%s"`